# Bind function to variable and evaluate each time variable is referenced

Tags: variables, setq

I want to set a variable to a function that is run every time the variable is used. Like [Lazy set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448939/5654930) in a makefile

```
(setq counter 0)
(setq counter (+ 1 counter))
counter ; actual: 1 wanted: 1
counter ; actual: 1 wanted: 2
counter ; actual: 1 wanted: 3
```

How would i go about doing this? =)

Comment: The question isn't very clear (to me). For a start, why are you using `(eval counter)` instead of just `counter` - why the double evaluation?

Comment: This is a very oddly phrased question. It would make sense if elisp had such a feature (a variant of it is available via `cl-symbol-macrolet`), but it doesn't. Why would a newbie to the language ask for a very specific solution to a problem better solved in a different way?

Comment: The question is unclear - both what you want and why. Why do you want a variable `counter` here instead of a (nullary) function `(counter)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want the variable `counter` to hold two things at once: instructions to increment the counter, and the current value of the counter. You can't have both at the same time. There are a few programming languages where you can define “magic” variables that do something whenever they're read, but Emacs Lisp isn't one of them.

While you can store instructions to increment the counter in a variable and call `eval` to execute these instructions, this isn't the normal way to do things and I can't see any benefit to it. Instructions are normally stored in functions. You can use a variable to contain the current value of the counter, and a function to increment it and return the current value.

```
(defvar current-counter-value 0)
(defun (counter-next)
  "Increment the counter and return the new value."
  (setq current-counter-value (1+ current-counter-value)))
(print (counter-next))
(print (counter-next))
(print (counter-next))
```

This prints 1, 2, 3.

Lisp allows a function and a variable to have the same name, so you can name both `counter` if you want. But this can get confusing.

Comment: According to the elisp manual you can have multiple assignments on a SYMBOL which is clearly what he is referring to - via "drawers". https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Variables.html#Variables

Comment: @HörmannHH That doesn't help. If you assign to both the variable `counter` and the function `counter`, the two are unrelated. Accessing the variable `counter` doesn't call the function `counter`, and calling the function `counter` doesn't reference the variable `counter` (unless the function code references it, the way it might reference any variable regardless of its name).

Answer (score 2):

The effect that `(eval counter)` increments `counter` in some sense can be reached by setting `counter` to a quoted closure call.
The `eval` evaluates the closure, the closure captures the actual counter and increments it at the `eval`. This solution does not address the `setq` part of your question.
There follows example code together with usage instructions.

Put the following code into an elisp file (e.g., `/tmp/test.el` under Linux) and run `emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load` on that file (menu item *Emacs Lisp > Byte-compile and Load*).

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

(let ((counter_value 0))
  (defun counter-fun () (cl-incf counter_value)))

(defvar counter '(counter-fun))
```

Put `(eval counter)` into the `*scratch*` buffer and evaluate it.
The first call gives 1 the second 2 and so on.

The code is tested with `emacs-version` 25.1.50.2.

Note, that it is even not necessary to put the incrementation of `counter_value` into a closure. You can also use `(defvar counter_value 0)` and the `defun` on top-level. Nevertheless the closure serves for information hiding. `counter_value` can only be accessed through `counter` in the version above.